# Insert page break if MS Word document is ending on an even number

Tags: ms-word

I have an ERP system which generates statements via a Word (.docx) template. The template uses bookmarks to fill in fields from the ERP system like balance, name etc.

Once produced these are grouped together as a PDF (of say 500 pages). At current setup we cannot print this double-sided as if one statement runs to three pages rather than two, it will put everything out of sync.

I would like some field in the footer of my .docx template which can insert a page break if:

1. This is an even numbered page; and
2. This is the last page of the document

e.g. Footer would visibly read

**Page 1 of 1**

but would have a page break after that.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for specific programming questions on existing projects. Please post your query at http://answers.microsoft.com or Super User. FYI, if you have the document set up with even and odd headers, Word will automatically add a blank page to ensure balanced page numbers

Comment: I've found two relevant links:
- Finding the last page: https://wordribbon.tips.net/T008712_Using_Last-page_Headers_and_Footers.html
- Conditional Page Break: https://rednectar.net/2016/07/24/conditional-page-break-in-ms-word/